# "User failed logon"

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

A friend of mine is using a Dell computer, running **Window 7 Home Premium.**
His account is the Administrator account. ( *There is one other functional user account on that computer that we do not have access to, if that matters* )

He recently tried to create a new user account, and apparently succeeded....until he tried to log in to that new account. When he tried, he got an error message something like the following:

> User profile failed the login process
>   User could not be logged in

I created and changed a password on that account, and received the same error message when logging in.
I then deleted that account, and created a new one, and got the same error message again.

What's wrong, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: See if "Method 1" fits your problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215/en-gb

Comment: @BigChris That's the problem, all right....I'll try the solutions there. Thanks!